# How to show lable "pay with card or debit card" option by default in Paypal in-context checkout

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card

I am using a paypal in-context checkout. 
but it show checkout as guest I want to"pay with card or debit card"

There is only option "pay with a credit card or debit card" not appearing in paypal login screen.

Can anyone tell me what should I need to do to see option there ?

[image]

[image]